# Renaming a categorical variable based on values of other variable in R

Tags: r

I have a sample dataset 'a' like this:

```
> a
  group marks  upd class
1     T     2   up     A
2     C     3   up  <NA>
3     C     4 down     B
4     T     5   up  <NA>
5     T     6 down     D
6     C     7   up  <NA>
7     T     1 down  <NA>
8     T     0 down     G
```

Here for each group (T or C) there are records in 'class' variable with values and null. Now for each group where ever the class is null ,I want that group to be renamed as T-NULL or C-NULL respectively. If the group (T or c) has some value in 'class' ,the group name should be as it is. How can we write a code in R for this?

Comment: (1) What have you tried? (2) Is `group` factor or character? (3) Grouping doesn't seem to matter here. (4) Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', based on the logical condition for NA values in 'class', we `paste` the NULL string to 'group' column and assign (`:=`) the modified string to 'group'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[is.na(class), group := paste(group, "NULL", sep="-")]
a
#    group marks  upd class
#1:      T     2   up     A
#2: C-NULL     3   up    NA
#3:      C     4 down     B
#4: T-NULL     5   up    NA
#5:      T     6 down     D
#6: C-NULL     7   up    NA
#7: T-NULL     1 down    NA
#8:      T     0 down     G
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
a$group[is.na(a$class)] <- paste(a$group[is.na(a$class)], "NULL", sep="-")
```

NOTE: We are assuming that the 'group' column is `character` class.  If it is `factor` class, convert to `character` class (`as.character` can be used or when reading the dataset use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`) or add both the 'C-NULL' and 'T-NULL' as `levels` to `factor` and then assign the modified string.

Comment: That last one is a very good solution for any number of group values. Nice!

Comment: @Gopala The `data.table` assignment would be fast as it happens on place.

Comment: Agree, although I don't use them. Use `dplyr` on data frames.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a$group = paste0(a$group, ifelse(is.na(a$class), "-NULL", ""))
```

Comment: Seems like a waste to spend time pasting to nothing when you could just paste the relevant values.